# AngularCli - Why I'm receiving syntax error during tests in JSON?

Tags: angular, service, angular-cli

I trying to test a component that when used in browser environment it is doing exactly what I want. The main method for the component is this:

```
login(auth: Credential): Observable<Access>     {
  const options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
  const json = JSON.stringify(auth);
  return this.http.post(this.authUrl, json, options)
    .map((res: Response) => {
      return res.json().token() || {};
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      if(error.status == 401) {
        return Observable.throw('Usuário ou senha inválidos!');
    }});
  }
}
```

What I can't understand is why when i run `ng test` the `console.log` says: `SyntaxError{}` and when I run this code through normal browser it just says that is a normal HttpError.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON>stringify(auth);
```

You have a `>` instead of a `.`.

Comment: Ops, that was a typing error. My bad. Already edited the post

Comment: Another problem is that you misspelled `options` at the `http.post` call.